# Extract lines from text with string as input

Tags: shell, here-string

How can extract lines that match the regexp string `^li` **from the text (not a file)** below using `sed` or something?

```
 linux
 loan
 litmus
 launch
```

I tried `grep` but I couldn't find a way to search within a quoted text, not a text file.

```
grep -n -i "^li" "linux
loan
litmus
launch"
```

Returns `No such file or directory`. And I don't want to save this text as a file before searching, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a [herestring](http://linux.die.net/abs-guide/x15683.html) (`<<<`) here to pass the string as input to `grep`, herestring returns a file descriptor, `grep` can then operate on that:

```
$ grep -ni "^li" <<<"linux
loan
litmus
launch"
```

**Output:**

```
1:linux
3:litmus
```

If your shell doesn't support herestrings, many shells don't, you can print your string and pipe it to `grep`:

```
$ echo "linux
loan
litmus
launch" | grep -n -i "^li"
1:linux
3:litmus
```

Or use heredoc (`<<`):

```
$ grep -ni "^li" <<EOF
> linux
> loan
> litmus
> launch
> EOF
1:linux
3:litmus
```

Answer (score 0):

With `sed` you can use the `sed -n '/^li/p'`

Using @heemayl example

```
$ echo "linux
> loan
> litmus
> launch" | sed -n '/^li/p'
linux
litmus
```

Comment: nice but the question is more about the input file than the command to use..

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
grep \^li
```

And then start typing your stuff. `grep` will read the terminal. `sed` will do the same. Use `CTRL+D` to stop them, and `... >saved_output_file` output redirections to save the effects.